Либо ошибка "HTTP/1.1 header parser received no bytes", либо не могу прочитать данные до конца
Все привет, 2 дня бился над, вроде бы, несложной задачей, не мог решить, помогите. Это простое клиент-серверное HTTP приложение, где клиент пересылает json как файл, а сервер парсит его и возвращает некоторые данные из него.
Вот клиентская часть
public class HttpClientRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, InterruptedException {

    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
            .build();

    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(new URI("http://localhost:8082"))
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .POST(ofFile(Path.of("src/main/resources/testForServer.json")))
                    .build();

    HttpResponse response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        System.out.println(response.headers());
        System.out.println(response.body());


    }
}

Вот серверная:
public class HttpServer {
    private final int port;

    public HttpServer(int port) {

        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run() {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket socket =  serverSocket.accept();
            processSocket(socket);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    private void processSocket(Socket socket) {
        try (socket;
             var in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
             var out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())
        ) {

            byte[] clientRequest = in.readNBytes(520);

            System.out.println(new String(clientRequest));

            //List<Integer> rsl = parse(clientRequest);

            byte[] body = """
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html lang="en">
                    <head>
                       <title>Salary</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                                        
                    <table>
                       <tr>
                           <th>Total income</th>
                           <th>Total tax</th>
                           <th>Total profit</th>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td>%s</td>
                           <td>%s</td>
                           <td>%s</td>
                       </tr>
                    </table>
                    </body>
                    </html>"""
                    .getBytes();
                    //.formatted(rsl.get(0), rsl.get(1), rsl.get(2)).getBytes();
            out.write("""
                    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    content-type: text/html
                    content-length: %s
                    """.formatted(body.length).getBytes());
            out.write(System.lineSeparator().getBytes());
            out.write(body);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private List<Integer> parse(byte[] clientRequest) {
        String str = new String(clientRequest, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String[] parts = str.split("\\r\\n\\r\\n");


        List<Integer> rsl = new LinkedList<>();
        int total_income = 0;
        int total_tax = 0;
        int total_profit = 0;

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            JsonNode jsonArray = objectMapper.readTree(parts[1]);
            for(JsonNode jsonNode : jsonArray) {
                total_income += jsonNode.get("salary").asInt();
                total_tax += jsonNode.get("tax").asInt();

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        total_profit = total_income - total_tax;
        rsl.add(total_income);
        rsl.add(total_tax);
        rsl.add(total_profit);
        return rsl;
    }
}

Если я в строке byte[] clientRequest = in.readNBytes(520); использую readAllBytes(), то процесс висит и не выдает никакого результата, как будто не может дойти до конца потока данных. Пробовал по-разному проходить по входящему потоку, и построково, и побайтово, но удается остановить только принудительно. Пробовал передавать json не как файл, а как строку, результат тот же.
Вторая часть проблемы, если ставить byte[] clientRequest = in.readNBytes(520);, то он считывает эти данные, но при парсинге скорей всего на строке JsonNode jsonArray = objectMapper.readTree(parts[1]) вылетает ошибка "HTTP/1.1 header parser received no bytes"

Метод readAllBytes() ожидает что клиент после передачи данных закроет соединение, т.к. Ваш клиент соединение не закрывает, сервер зависает.
Метод readNBytes() читает n-байт, не больше не меньше, т.е. если в потоке меньше n байт, он будет ждать, пока не появится достаточно данных, либо он так-же может прочитать не весь ответ, если в нём будет больше данных.
Попробуйте метод readLine(), я думаю это решит Вашу проблему
